# Strange tmux status-bar rendering issues iterm2

Tags: macos, terminal, tmux, iterm2, iterm

I'm running into this strange issue with my tmux in iterm where it appears to be rendering on the wrong line, but this causes strange rendering issues to happen

Here is the basic behavior:
[image]

You'll notice the menubar is offset by one line. This is fine, for the most part, except when I start entering tmux commands I get behavior like this:

[image]

I've also noticed that sometimes the menu bar will entirely disappear and I won't be able to show which sessions i have open. I've also noticed that sometimes if I select the text in my terminal with my mouse, it will select text one-line up from what I expected to select.

I've tried a bunch of things to debug this, including:

- re-install tmux
- clear tmux-resurrect history
- restart my computer
- reinstall iterm
- resizing the iterm window (both manually, and using cmd+ and cmd, which I have a theory was what triggered this behavior)

I've also noticed that if  I run tmux in the default terminal macOS application it behaves normally with no issues.

Does anyone have any ideas of things I could try?

Comment: I've also tried  `tmux set-option status off &&  tmux set-option status on`

Comment: same issue here

Answer (score 0):

I have unchecked all of these options, and the strange behavior disappears.
[image]

Comment: I tried this but still have the issue

Comment: sometimes this issue appear when I plug/unplug the monitor, how about try disable the gpu?